# How implement vue3 dropzone without vue3's "composition api"?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-dropzone

I'm migrating a huge project from vue2/vuetify2 to the new version 3 for both frameworkds

We are using the "vue2 dropzone" which is not compatible with vue3 and therefore have to upgrade to the newer "vue3 dropzone", see here: https://github.com/Yaxian/vue3-dropzone

The examples I've found how to use the vue3dropzone are all using the "composition api" for vue3. I can't figure out how to "translate" it to the "non composition api" syntax. Changing the syntax on all the existing pages that use the dropzone would take too much time so some help with this would be much appreciated.

Alternitevly, if there is some other file-upload-component good to use I'm also interested in knowing about it.

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that the library relies on Composition API based [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html), e.g. `useDropzone`.  Bad news is that these are not translatable to Options API.  Maybe good news is that you wouldn't have to do a complete rewrite to Composition API. The [setup() function](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html) can be used to handle composables / other Composition API code, while being used in what are otherwise Options API components with all your familiar `methods`, `data`, `props` etc. options.